# In Eclipse Tomcat launch config, difference between declaring launch env variable, having -Dargument, and catalina.properties entry

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, lifecycle

What is the Eclipse launch - Tomcat startup "life cycle" for these three actions?

I find that having java -Dargument is the most effective of all. Obviously, there needs no explanation for this, as the jvm sys variables are set right off the bat.

However, why are env variables, set in the env tab in Tomcat launch config, effective only after the initial server resource loading? Any variables in tomcat startup resources are not resolved, as far as I can see. The variables are resolvable only when loaded listeners start their rounds of polling.

And are catalina.properties entries effective only after web app loading? At least it seems to be that way to me.

I can't find any Eclipse-Tomcat documentation on the "life cycle" of container variables.

What are the dynamics of the variables declared in Eclipse-launch env tab? How and when are they "injected" into the container? Are they really set as system env variables by eclipse launch? Why are they not resolvable during tomcat startup?